# Using command sed replace variable with regular expression error

Tags: regex, linux, sed

When I learn the command about sed,I find this problem which I can't solve.The txt that I want handle is following:

```
myBook:test yetongxue$ cat test.txt 
    def IsNonce_strSet(self):
        """
        判断随机字符串是否存在
        @return true 或 false
        """
        return self._values.has_key('nonce_str')
```

And this is my command and result:

```
myBook:test yetongxue$ sed "s/return self._values.has_key\(\)/mark1 \1 mark2/g" test.txt 
    def IsNonce_strSet(self):
        """
        判断随机字符串是否存在
        @return true 或 false
        """
        mark1  mark2('nonce_str')
```

I am puzzled about the position of mark2, which should be after ('nonce_str').
Like this:

> mark1 ('nonce_str') mark2

Anybody can explain this? Thanks very much!

And Further,how can I white the regular expression so I can match the string only ***nonce_str***.
My command is:

> sed "s/return self._values.has_key('()')/mark1 \1 mark2/g" test.txt

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression `\(\)` matches and captures an empty string in `sed`.

Apparently, you expect to capture a set of literal parentheses and the text between them?

```
sed ´s/return self\._values\.has_key\(([^()]*)\)/mark1 \1 mark2/'
```